# Python syntax error when I use if on same line

Tags: python

I must be doing something stupid but I just don't see it. I could not get the following simple code to work.

```
>>> def a_bigger_than_b(a,b):
...   'Yes' if a > b
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    'Yes' if a > b
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Found [This](http://pythontesting.net/python/annoyed-ternary-operator/) and I agree with him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def a_bigger_than_b(a,b):
...   return 'Yes' if a > b else 'No!'
```

Actually your using it as `Ternary Operator` in such case you need else

i think you must give else this can be well understood by

first

```
c='Yes' if a > b
```

what will be the value for a if a is smaller than b this case is ambiguous so else is must

correct syntax

```
c='Yes' if a > b else 'No!'
```

A detailed explanation was given by [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)

```
*On 9/29/2005, Guido decided to add conditional expressions in the
    form of "X if C else Y".

    The motivating use case was the prevalance of error-prone attempts
    to achieve the same effect using "and" and "or".

    Previous community efforts to add a conditional expression were
    stymied by a lack of consensus on the best syntax.  That issue was
    resolved by simply deferring to a BDFL best judgment call.*
```

Comment: Very surprised that I can't have a standalone if, thanks for your reply. Just tried that I could not even have an empty else. I really don't understand why it is done this way.

Comment: Can I not doing anything if a is smaller than b ? I did not use a variable thou

Comment: You can have an `if` without `else` but there is no need to have it in a one-liner.

Comment: @AskandLearn You should distinguish between the `if` in the ternary operator and the `if` as control statement. In the latter case, of course you can omit the `else`.

Comment: @glglgl yes, I did not know ternary operator in python is like that. I know it now and I will remember it.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax resembles me a bit of Perl.

I am not sure what exactly you want

```
def a_bigger_than_b(a,b):
    'Yes' if a > b
```

to do; there are several possimble interpretations.

Amongst the ones already mentioned, you could as well want

```
def a_bigger_than_b(a, b):
    if a > b: return 'Yes'
```

which does nothing in the `<=` case and eventually reaches the end of the function, where (implicitly) `None` is returned.

This is the one-liner syntax for Python, quite equvalent to the `do_whatever if foo` syntax in Perl.

Be aware that a function must always return a value; if you don't explicitly, `None` is returned implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You may change if statement in simpler one:

```
def a_bigger_than_b(a, b):
    return a > b and 'Yes'
```

Comment: ... in which case `False` is returned if `a <= b`.

Comment: Yup, but may be changed to anything else than `False`, eg. `a > b and 'Yes' or 'Noooo'`

Comment: In this case yes, but in the general case, `a if b else c` is leaner than `b and a or c`. If `a` is a false value, you get `c` although `b` is true. (As said, that doesn't apply here, as `'Yes'` is true.)